# Can a Custom Validation Rule in Aurelia call other existing rules?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I want to create a custom validation rule for the Aurelia Validator plugin. Essentially, I have a semicolon-delimited string of email addresses (in a To) field and I'd like to split this string and run email validations on each individual email address. I have the following so far (there are null check issues, but ignore that for now)

```
ValidationRules.customRule('multiEmail', (value, obj) => {
    var emails = value.split(';');
    emails.forEach(() => {
        // Call the existing email validation functionality rule for                  each value?
    });
});
```

Is this possible?